# Crash while trying to get data from other class

Tags: java, android, class, crash

I'm trying to get random letter from different class/activity, but for some reason it crashes

```
randomLogic randomFunc;
    String resultRandom = randomFunc.randomLetter(); <- crashes here 
    randomKana.setText(resultRandom);
```

And here is the other class:

```
    public String randomLetter(){
    int hiraArray = sFirst.length;
    String hiragana_array = sFirst[RANDOM.nextInt(hiraArray)];
    return hiragana_array;
}
```

Comment: `randomFunc` is not initialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only declared `randomLogic randomFunc;`. But you have not initialized.

Also if `randomLogic` is a Activity class you should not instantiate a Activity class. Its only declared in manifest and has its own lifecycle.

To pass values between activities use `intent.putExtra` methods

Comment: Thank you I completely forgot about initialization, Thank you.

Comment: @Taziz but is it activity class that you instantiate?

Comment: Well 4 minuts until I can accept this answer, and no it's not activity class

Comment: @Taziz This "from different class/activity" from your question prompted me to expand my answer further coz you did mention activity

Comment: well sorry I'm new to android development and still need to understand how android programming works so it's my mistake randomLogic is a Class that generates random letter and number and shows user on screen, it's more like a guessing game